# CRUD operations with Firebase and Express JS

Tags: jquery, firebase, express

I currently have a notes application that saves data to a local JSON database, and i cant seem to find an example on how to actually do crud with firebase. Here is my current Code:

```
    // A function for getting all notes from the db
var getNotes = function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/api/notes",
    method: "GET"
  });
};

// A function for saving a note to the db
var saveNote = function(note) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/api/notes",
    data: note,
    method: "POST",
    
  });
};
```

I am trying to figure out how to actually convert this so that it saves in firebase and not locally, how would i do this? I am relatively new to firebase, I havent used it before.

Comment: Are you using firebase-functions?

Comment: @BhumilSarvaiya Hi, No i am not, would it be a good idea to use firebase functions?